# Loading gif in page:failed to load resource Cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

For some time I'm trying to develop my own app using cordova. The first page I created is the login. When the user clicks on the submit button I check the credentials by sending them using ajax. Meanwhile I want to display a loading animation,and I found how to do it:

> $.mobile.loading('show')

It works..almost. It only shows a black circle on the middle of the screen. I checked the console only to find :

> Failed to load resource
> ajax-loader.gif (0,0)

I ran multiple test: I commented the  security policy,copied the image in different folders,checked the spelling and finally created my own span with `url(images/ajax-loader.gif)` and ..it worked. Then I did the same thing with the original loader(I found its span in the DOM explorer) and added an inline style `url(images/ajax-loader.gif)`..it worked!

Finally I realised this:
[image]

It is like it tries to load the same image from two different sources. How can I fix it?

Other details:Jquery 2.0.0/Jquery-mobile 1.4.5

Comment: What's the path to the stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

This is some weird behaviour still not explained-so ANYONE can post the correct reason/explanation for this- but I will post the fix.
I took a look at this [post](http://forums.no-margin-for-errors.com/discussion/434/not-loading-ajax-loader.gif/p1) and thought to give it a try.
This is how the css looks like(I edited it in debug mode so it should be overridden) :`background: url(.././images/ajax-loader.gif)`

Now it works but the question IS still active.